# What is the purpose of idle and break characters in USART?

Tags: embedded

I'm currently writing some code to implement USART on an STM32F4 microcontroller and was wondering how to effectively use the idle and break characters. Do they serve a special purpose or is their use application-specific?

Comment: For asynchronous serial data there is only an idle level - for logic voltages (not RS232) this is logic 1 - there isn’t an idle character. Break also isn’t a character: it’s a logic 0 for a minimum of one full character time (1 start bit, 7/8 data bits, optional parity bit AND crucially the stop bit) so that the character isn’t framed correctly. The maximum duration of break isn’t defined. Historically break used to signal from a terminal that it needed attention; yes that would be a special purpose which is application-specific.

Comment: "the stop bit" - I guess this means probably two stop bits as most UARTs allow selection of 1 or 2. So to guarantee a break is detected at the receiver the minimum width of break must be 12 bits (baud) wide; if you don't know the baud rate then you'd have to make assumption of perhaps at least 110 baud and so break time of 12/110s - 0.11s.

Comment: A quick web research revealed [this presentation](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/training/technical/product_training/4f/cc/bb/f7/04/99/41/66/STM32L4_Peripheral_USART.pdf/files/STM32L4_Peripheral_USART.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.STM32L4_Peripheral_USART.pdf) that supports @barny's comment on page 9. -- Also the Wikipedia page about [UART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver-transmitter) tells us a lot. -- The OP could have done this... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The use of IDLE and BREAK is mostly related to *synchronous* communications (although you could use both concepts in asynchronous mode as well).

Because  there is a continuous bitstream flowing on the line in synchronous mode, there is no way to send *nothing* - To be able to do that, the IDLE pattern (normally all ones) is often used. It simply means there is no data on the line.

The BREAK pattern (normally all zeroes) is often used to signal an out-of-band notification in synchronous protocols - For example as a start-of-packet signature.

The exact use of IDLE and BREAK is up to the low-level line protocol.